# Update to Office 365 version 1912 breaks the ODBC connection (32 bit)?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, office365

Since the Monthly Channel Office 365 Update to version 1912 on December 19, 2019, the ODBC connection in our MS Access application appears to be broken.  Uninstalling the version 1912 update fixes it.  I don't see any information about this problem on the Release Notes for Office Insiders web page.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific re: *appears to be broken*?